# Dynamically create a list of variables gives error RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create two lists with dynamic variables but I get the following error:

`RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0`

```
List<bool> variableOne= [];
List<bool> variableTwo= [];

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   variableOne[i] = false;
   variableTwo[i] = true;
}
```

The output that I want is:

```
variableOne[0] = false;
variableTwo[0] = true;
variableOne[1] = false;
variableTwo[1] = true;
variableOne[2] = false;
variableTwo[2] = true;
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create empty list, the list does not have any elements that you can't access elements by using index. it means that you can't assign a value to a index of a list that is not existed yet.

you can use `add` method to add values to your list and then the indexes will be created:

```
List<bool> variableOne = [];
List<bool> variableTwo = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   variableOne.add(false);
   variableTwo.add(true);
}
```

happy coding...